# LPRUN on AppVeyor with a reference to a custom NUGET repo reference

Tags: nuget, linqpad, appveyor

I am using a LinqPad script to automate an internal health check via AppVeyor.

The script references a custom nuget package hosted on our appveyor account.

The build does the following:

1. Pulls down a GitHub repo
2. via LPRUN executes health-check.linq

*Locally this works.*

*On AppVeyor it does not.*

I have the following build process

**SETUP**

```
Via chocolatey --> install Linqpad5        
choco install linqpad5
```

**BUILD**

```
nuget install Example.Package
```

[this is our own NUGET package hosted on AppVeyor  [SUCCESS]]

```
xcopy "c:\projects\example_project\utilities" %AppData%\LINQPad\ /i
```

[copy our custom NuGetSources.xml file containing our nuget repo location to linqpads folder]

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\LINQPad5\"
lprun "C:\projects\example_project\utilities\health-check.linq"
```

**ERROR**

*'Error downloading 'Example.Package' - An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Example.Package' from source 'Example Company Repo'.*

Does anyone have any hints on how to reference a custom NUGET repo from a LINQPAD script on APPVEYOR?

**More Info**

We use AppVeyor for our CI.  It allows us to write our own custom NUGET packages for *internal* use within our own projects.

We have a repository ('FinPad') that contains numerous .linqpad files that automate our processes & house keeping.

Each FinPad script contains a reference to a package called 'FairGo.FinPower' on our own AppVeyor nuget repo.  This custom nuget package contains numerous 3rd party .Net DLLs & our own custom code to connect to a 3rd party financial loan management system we use as a backend - http://www.finpower.com.au/ (hosted by us on Azure)

One such script is a 'Health Check' - this confirms a specific environment is operating OK.

For our TEST environment I wanted to schedule our 'health check linqpad' script to run every 15 minutes (and on failure alert stackify & slack)

The process works as follows ( using a custom Azure build machine from AppVeyor)

1. every 15 minutes
2. run a custom AppVeyor build called 'Health Check TEST' -->
3. pull down the GitHub project 'FinPad' to c:\projects\finpad
4. before build --> choco install linqpad5
5. Run the below command to copy our own nuget.config (with our own FairGo nuget repo references) to the location linqpad wants for reference

copy "c:\projects\finpad\utilities\nuget.config" "C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Roaming\NuGet"

*** the above nuget.config contains the url / username /password to our appveyor nuget repo in plain text

6. build --> cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\LINQPad5\"
7. after build --> lprun "C:\projects\FinPad\utilities\health-check-test.linq"

For reference the Health check linqpad file is
http://share.linqpad.net/tuthme.linq

Locally this works fine (I manually configured our NUGET repo by the LinqPad GUI locally & ***assumed it only updated the nuget.config in 'C:\Users\ME\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config'.***  (so I added this file to the repo & copy it every build)

On AppVeyor the build gives the below error

Downloading NuGet package FairGo.FinPower and dependencies from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Error downloading 'FairGo.FinPower' - Unable to find package 'FairGo.FinPower'.
Command exited with code 1

*I have this running through a Console App now - but would really like to get this working through a LinqPad script if possible.*

Comment: Can you please provide appveyor.yml and health-check.linq content? Feel free to send them to team@appveyor.com if you do not want to post it here.

Comment: question posted on appveyor discussion too - will post answer here too once given - thanks

Comment: The same people including me are answer on AppVeyor discussions forum and questions related to AppVeyor here on SO. So we will ask you for .yml and .linq file to investigate anyway. I do not see your post on http://help.appveyor.com though.

Comment: @ilyaf  I posted it again as a discussion (this time a question rather than a problem)  it says 'That discussion is awaiting moderation.'

Comment: http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/questions/3256-lprun-on-appveyor-with-a-reference-to-a-custom-nuget-repo-reference

Comment: Which version of LINQPad are you running? Only the recent betas will detect a copy of NuGetSources.xml in the LINQPad.exe folder.

Comment: @JoeAlbahari I am using choco install linqpad5 - I managed to get this half working. I should have been copying the nuget.config file --- but the error i get is 'As you dont have a LINQPad premium/Developer edition you can only search for nuget packages that include LINQPad samples - I hoping I can find out how to install Nuget via chocolatey with a license key – (if I remote desktop to the appveyor build server & add a license key it works until next build) - I will investigate adding a license key via the command line - thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need a license to use LPRun - paid features relate to the GUI only. So without a license, the NuGet package browser will be restricted but you can still run scripts that reference NuGet packages. Can you tell me exactly what you're doing?

Comment: @JoeAlbahari I have added more info to the original question - hope that helps - happy to give more info/a demo if you like.  thx